# SSRS ignore a row for total

Tags: reporting-services

I built a report in SQL Server Reporting Services using a cube.

[image]

This report is grouped based on country names and as you can see in the report, the column Pennsylvania is built manually by summing (Philadelphia,Harrisburg and Pittsburgh). But, in the total, I don't want the Pennsylvania value included. I need the total like 378-82=296. What expression should I give to ignore Pennsylvania in the total?

Comment: Why have you added a manual column? Should be this column a group?

Comment: If you look at total's formula, it should include all fields of your dataset

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use a calculated field to mark the values you want to keep.

- Go into the dataset properties
- Go to the Fields tab
- Add a Calculated field
- use an expression like this:

  =IIf(Fields!StateName.Value = "Pennsylvania", Nothing, Fields!NumberToTotal.Value)
- replace the two columns names in the expression with your actual column names.
- Now, in the Total row in your table you can simply Sum this new field to get the filtered total.